# What's the best way to obfuscate non-sensitive cookie data in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement some functionality as described by DHH here:

[image]

Source: https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui

Since the user id is visible in the URL, it's not really sensitive data. Am I right in thinking that if I was going to store it in a cookie, it should be obfuscated in some way to prevent users tampering with it easily?

What's the best method to go about obfuscating such data in Rails and then retrieving it in JavaScript?

Comment: The rails `session` cookie is not parseable on the client - it's encrypted server-side so you don't need to do any additional obfuscation if you're using it. That's why a Rails server can cafely look up the current user from the sessiom

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question :). My question has nothing to do with the session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscating it is not the right answer since whatever you do to the value it still needs to be readable in the client and there are no true secrets on the client side. Which just makes this security by obscurity with no real value.

While Rails has both [encrypted and signed cookies](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) these both use secret_key_base which you don't want to expose to the client.

Rather what you want to do is to make sure to make this is a separate cookie from the actual session cookie that stores the user id for authentication and reset it on every request. Don't use it for anything except the front-end and always rely on the encrypted session storage (cookie) on the backend.

A naive implementation:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user_cookie, if: :user_signed_in?

  def set_user_cookie
    cookies[:x_current_user] = current_user.id
  end
end
```

If you are using Devise/Warden you can use [one of the hooks](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/hassox/warden/Warden%2FHooks:after_set_user) to do this instead of doing it in your `ApplicationController`.

Even if the user tampers with the cookie then the only result is that they are excluding another user from the list.